# C++ converting a binary string to it's 16 bit two's compliment binary string

Tags: c++, string, binary, twos-complement

I'm trying to implement a solution I found but it is not giving the proper answer.

Here is the solution: http://2scomplimentcpp.blogspot.com.au/

Basically the input is a binary string, I take that string convert it to a decimal and then use the code in the link but it only gives me the right answer sometimes... in two of the test cases it gives me the wrong answer...when I use the binary string "01" it returns "0000000000000001" instead of "1111111111111111". In the other case when I input the string "10101" it returns "0000000000010101" instead of "0000000000001011"...

What am I doing wrong here?  Ideally I would rather not have to cnovert it to a decimal first...is there a way I can simply take the binary string I am given and convert it directly into its two's complement binary string(16 bit)?

For example, if I am given the binary string of "01", the

```
   int numBin = binary_to_decimal(s);
    numBin = (0 <= numBin) ? numBin : (-1)*numBin;
    int two = ((bitset<16>)numBin).flip().to_ulong();

    return bitset<16>(++two).to_string();
```

Comment: How are you performing the binary_to_decimal conversion?.I tried your code along with std::stoi (for converting from binary to decimal ) and it seems to work fine. https://www.ideone.com/qUxVzs

Comment: That code does not work fine--it returns the wrong leading binary values...so in the case of "10101" it returns "11111111101011"---the "01011" is correct but it should have leading 0's instead of 1's...

Comment: I am confused. For "01" you expect 1 as leading value(which is what I would expect) but not for 10101?

Comment: Please post the implementation of `binary_to_decimal`. (Also, it is bad practice to use `using namespace std` so try to remove it and prepend `std::` where necessary.

Comment: I think '(0 <= numBin) ? numBin :' is redundant. You want to negate the number in every case. Am I right?